# Java : Custom Timestamp Format : verify format to microsec precision

Tags: java, timestamp

My Objective is
to create a java class that can handle the below two requirements

**(A) 1. Verify if the format of a timestamp matches with expected format.**
CCYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss'.0000000000+'uh:um"
Ex: the expected format is not static.

It may be either of these
    "2013-09-10T18:30:20.123456+10:00" or
    "2013-09-10T18:30:20.123+10:00".
I am not bothered about the
    precision and value. Only the format matters.

**(B)  2. Verify if the timestamp is in a certain range.**
Ex: Verify if the timestamp is in
    between "2013-09-10 18:27" and "2013-09-10 18:33". (verification is only upto minute level precision) (may be a delta of + or - 2min)

---

> As suggested by one of the member, I have edited the post to target at
>   One specific question.

***The QUESTION :***

How to validate the custom timestamp upto microsec precision using JAVA class ?

The two arguments for this class will be

1) Expected FORMAT as a String

2) timestamp value as a String

Based on analysis from various search results, below is my understanding :

1. Java (by default) does not parse/format Timestamp at microsecond level( I used SimpleDateFormat)
2. If 6 digits are given in milliseconds place, it will re-calculate the value into seconds and the dateformat will be updated and the new dateformat will have 3 digits in milliseconds precision.
3. I have also seen a thread which suggests to use java.sql.Timestamp.

Tried this approach but not working.
I was not able to convert my strTimestamp 2013-09-10T18:30:20.123456+10:00 into Timestamp object.

```
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(strTimestamp); 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

I was not able convert my input format into Timestamp object.

---

I have a workaround to validate using regular expression :

```
2013-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]):(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]).[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\+10:00
```

The problem with this reg ex is that, my expected timestamp format is not static. So i have to use a regex for every pattern.

**So I am trying to figure out if there is any robust solution in java, which can be self sufficient even if the expected format changes.**

Comment: limit the number of questions in your question to one. Ask separate questions if you have to.

Comment: I edited the post to target one specific question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## java.time in Java 8

[JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defined a new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history). Its date-time class resolves to nanoseconds. That gives you 9 digits after the decimal point.

The java.time package is inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) but entirely re-architected. Concepts are similar.

Like Joda-Time, the java.time package uses ISO 8601 formats as its defaults for parsing and formatting. So you can input or output strings such as `2013-09-10T18:30:20.123456789+10:00`.

An early release of Java 8 is available now. Official release should be this month.

A project to backport this package to earlier versions of Java was underway. I do not know of its current status or success. The backport project is independent of Oracle and the OpenJDK project.

## Milliseconds

The old bundled classes, java.util.Date & .Calendar, use a precision of milliseconds.

Ditto for the excellent [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, milliseconds precision.

So not enough digits in the fractional seconds to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A `java.sql.Timestamp` is not going to help you, because that *is* a `java.util.Date`.

The code is fairly simple, if you use the right format String with `SimpleDateFormat`, which you let do the heavy lifting. Here's an entire working solution:

```
public static boolean isNear(String timestamp, int microPlaces, Date near, int minutes) {
    if (!timestamp.matches(".*\\.\\d{" + microPlaces + "}\\D.*") {
        return false;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(timestamp.replaceAll(":(?=\\d\\d$)", ""));
        return Math.abs(date.getTime() - near.getTime()) <= minutes * 60000;
    } catch (ParseException ignore) {
        return false; // string was not of correct format
    }
}
```

This may not be exactly what you had in mind - if not, you should be able to use it as a basis for what you want. The key points are:

- The `S` format string means "microseconds", and it doesn't require *all* the digits - so your timestamp can have any number
- Java 6 needs the colon removed from the timezone. Java 7 doesn't need this - use the `X` format string instead of `Z`
- A failure to parse a date from the input throws a `ParseException` - do what you want with this event
- I chose to make the API give central date for the range and a +/- minute value. You may need to pass two dates - up to you. Use `Date.before()` and `Date.after()` to compare if you do that.

Here's some test code testing your examples and a couple of edge cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Date near = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm").parse("2013-09-10T18:32");
    System.out.println(isNear("2013-09-10T18:30:20.123456+10:00", near, 2));
    System.out.println(isNear("2013-09-10T18:30:20.123+10:00", near, 2));
    System.out.println(isNear("2013-09-10T18:10:20.123+10:00", near, 1));
    System.out.println(isNear("XXXX-09-10T18:10:20.123+10:00", near, 1));
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: The requirement is to validate if the actual timestamp format matches the expected timestamp format to microsec precision.

As you mentioned, the above code doesn't require all the digits in microsecs, and timestamp can have any number.  

So, this code does not handle the requirement.  
  


When expected timestamp has 6 digits, the class should mandate all 6 digits. If not return false/exception.  

    When expected timestamp has 3 digits, the class should mandate only 3 digts. If not return false/exception.

Comment: As mentioned, I already have workaround to do this.  
Parse to check for valid date using SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");  
Since this does not actually verify all digits in microseconds, I could do a length check on the string to confirm no of digits.  
But I feel all this is a wague way of doing things.  
And I am looking for solutions where Java does this simple and straight forward. I am using Java 6.

Comment: So you want to check if there is either 3 or 6 digits of microseconds only? Ie if not 3 or 6 then return false?

Comment: `Expected format are either of these :`   
`2013-09-17T10:31:30.123+10:00   or`  `2013-09-17T10:31:30.123456+10:00    or`     `2013-09-17T10:31:30.123456789+10:00`

`the expected format will be passed as argument to class. It should match the exact format.`

Comment: there are three of them above(3/6/9). and it is only these three formats that are expected.

Comment: I've changed the method to also accept the number of nicrosecond places. Regex is used to assert the number of places is as specified. The method will only return true if the number of micro places is correct and the timestamp parses and is near the specified date.

Comment: This mandates the user to provide the microPlaces in addition to the expected format. I think, this should be enhanced to capture the number of microPlaces from the number of 'S' in expected timestamp format and then use the rest of the code to verify format and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Really I`m also trying to find answer to this problem. As I have no ability to add comment to the Bohemian answer. I want to mention that 'S' pattern in SimpleDateFormat is used not for **microseconds** but for **milliseconds**. It means that for pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ" provided microsecond digits in string would be parsed as milliseconds.
So the first three digits would be passed as XXX seconds and their value value would be added to date. So we can receive mistake about 16 minutes.