# Java : Custom Timestamp Format : Verify value range to minute precision

Tags: java, timestamp

My Objective is
to create a java class that can handle the below two requirements

**(A) 1. Verify if the format of a timestamp matches with expected format.**
CCYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss'.0000000000+'uh:um"
Ex: the expected format
    is not static. It may be either of these
    "2013-09-10T18:30:20.123456+10:00" or
    "2013-09-10T18:30:20.123+10:00".
I am not bothered about the
    precision and value. Only the format matters.

**(B)  2. Verify if the timestamp is in a certain range.**
Ex: Verify if the timestamp is in between "2013-09-10 18:27" and "2013-09-10 18:33". (verification is only upto minute level precision) (may be a delta of + or - 2min)

The question on first objective was posted here 
[Java : Custom Timestamp Format : verify format to microsec precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820153/java-custom-timestamp-format-verify-format-to-microsec-precision)

In refrence to the second objective : 
***The Question :***

**How to verify if the timestamp is within the given range to minute precision using Java class?**

The inputs to the class will be three arguments

1. The timestamp to be verfied as a string
2. The lower range timestamp as string
3. the higer range timestamp as string.

I tried this

```
String date = "2013-09-10T18:30:12.123456789+10:00"
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm"); 
date = date.substring(0,22)+"+10:00"; 
Date newDate = df.parse(date); 
timestamp_value = df2.format(newDate);
```

timestamp_value is now 201309101830
Check if timestamp_value is greater than 201309101827.
Check if timestamp_value is lesser_ than 201309101833
This is okay.

**However, i feel this i a crude way of achieving it, so I would like to know if there is any better solution. 
If i could convert to Timestamp object, i think .before and .after can help. Any suggestions ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) "2013-09-10T18:30:20.123+10:00" is XSD dateTime format and the best way to parse it is this

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date);
```

if date format is wrong  IllegalArgumentException will be thrown

2) to verify if a timestamp is within a certain range the easiest way is to get millis from dates, truncate to minutes and use arithmetic comparison  `t >= from - delta && t <= to + delta`

Comment: Regarding XMLGregorianCalendar,
It will throw exception if the date format is incorrect.
But can it also verify if the given date is as per my expected format  ?

Comment: Since, i dont need to verify the range after seconds precision, 
I am able to use the XMLGregorianCalendar to convert
the custom formatted string into to java.util.Date and then convert to long using getTime();
Once I have all three dates in millis., I am doing an arithmetic comparison

Comment: much simpler: GregorianCalendar gc = xgc.toGregorianCalendar(); gc.getTimeInMillis();

Comment: yeah, seems simpler
long value = xgc.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();